# Need a way to use button click functionality vs GetKeyDown in Coroutine

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, coroutine, keycode, animator

This animator script works, however, in place of the Keycode input inside the WHILE LOOP, I need to use a UI button for mobile, which I haven't been able to figure out. I found an answer about putting a wrapper around it to make method available to click event, but have no idea how that's supposed to work within update function. It took me a long time to get this far, being a newbie to unity AND c#, so if you could provide a detailed answer or suggestion, I can get my life back, please help if you can.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using SWS;

public class goat_question : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator anim;
    public GameObject player;
    public Text ResultText;
    public Text AnswerText;  
    public Text AnswerText2;
    public Button GoatButton;

  

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        Button btn = GoatButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);

    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
    }
   
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()

    {
        if (AnswerText.text.Equals(AnswerText2.text))

        {                                         

            StartCoroutine(GoatWalkPathCoroutine());        

        }

         IEnumerator GoatWalkPathCoroutine()
        {
            while (true)  
            {              

                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K))  
                {
                    anim.Play("goat_hi_walk");
                    player.GetComponent<splineMove>().enabled = true;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(27);
                    anim.Play("goat_hi_licking");

                }
                yield return null;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm gonna submit my comment as an answer

Comment: Ty Irvine, I don't know if you read my description.  The code works, and the function is called exactly the same with your update as it does with mine.  The issue is not the coroutine running, but the CONDITION I'm using in the while loop is a Keycode, which will not work on mobile. I need to use with UI Button and don't know how to get a button click to work inside coroutine, or what the workaround is.  This issue is not resolved. Please see the title.  The coroutine is running fine.  This is about the need to replace Keydown/keycode with a ui button click.  Thanks. NOT RESOLVED.

Comment: I’m so sorry. I deleted my answer. I misread the question. Did Justin’s answer solve this for you?

Comment: Ty, yes it did.  Thank you for trying to help.  Greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a separate script for just the UI button, have a bool called isClicked or something, and when the button gets clicked set that to true. In this main script, you can reference the one you just made, and instead of the Input.GetKey, you can say, `if(otherScript.isClicked)`.

Comment: I'm sure this is the answer but, as I said I'm newbie to c# and unity.  I created script and added this code and it's creating an error in my animator script.  I'm sure it's something simple.public class isClickedGoat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isClicked;

    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        isClicked = true;
    }


}